# Clock problem when programming ATMega328P over ICSP pins

Tags: arduino, spi

I'm following this [example](https://learn.adafruit.com/program-an-avr-or-arduino-using-raspberry-pi-gpio-pins/overview) from Adafruit that shows how to program an AVR such as ATMega328P from a Raspberry Pi, using the AVR's ICSP pins.

I run all the steps and it is working fine except a single issue with the clock. I'm testing the traditional blink example from Arduino IDE, that blinks an LED with intervals of 1 second. The problem is that instead of 1 second, my LED is blinking every 15 seconds. Any idea of what might be causing such a problem?

I using Raspberry 4 with Raspbian Buster and an ATMega328P. This is the code I'm compiling with Arduino IDE:

```
/*
  Blink
  Turns on an LED on for one second, then off for one second, repeatedly.

  This example code is in the public domain.
 */

// Pin 13 has an LED connected on most Arduino boards.
// give it a name:
int led = 13;

// the setup routine runs once when you press reset:
void setup() {
  // initialize the digital pin as an output.
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
}

// the loop routine runs over and over again forever:
void loop() {
  digitalWrite(led, HIGH);   // turn the LED on (HIGH is the voltage level)
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
  digitalWrite(led, LOW);    // turn the LED off by making the voltage LOW
  delay(1000);               // wait for a second
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TBH I do not think this is a Pi issue.  The chip could have the wrong clock speed set in its internal fuses or have a different external oscillator crystal.

You need to run the `avrdude` program from the command line using the **-c** and the **-v** options then look at the result using something like [this fuse calculator](https://www.engbedded.com/fusecalc).  My guess is the device has the div by 8 bit set...

You can reset these fuses - always worth doing so you know the state of the chips (esp low cost clones).
opOptions

Comment: Ok, thanks. Sorry but I'm not an expert. How do I reset the fuses?

Comment: Ok, I just checked how I reset the fuses. Now I have another issue, because it doesn't reset the fuses. It says `avrdude: safemode: efuse changed! Was 5, and is now fd
Would you like this fuse to be changed back? [y/n]` and if I say yes, it freezes. I'm will create another question in Arduino Stack Exchange.